# Passing function variables into a second function changes variable values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I imagine this is just a Javascript-oriented feature that I'm not aware of, but coming from a C# back-end environment means I assume a lot of JS's functionality works the same, which isn't usually the case.

With the below code, I am trying to pass the values of `field` and `section` further down into a second function defined on rows.each, however when I check in the debugged the `field` and `section` variables being used in the line `if (classList.contains(field) && classList.contains(section))` have different values that what I expect them to have.

They are obviously being changed somewhere, but I am unsure for what reason.

```
function setValidationRowToFailure(field, section) {
        var rows = $("#PeekInstruction .validation-row");
        rows.each(function(field, section) {
            var classList = $(this).find(".validation-row-value").attr("id");
            if (classList.contains(field) && classList.contains(section)) {
                $(this).removeClass("validation-row-success");
                $(this).addClass("validation-row-failure");
            }
        })
    }
```

To further support my point that the original values of field and section aren't being used, they are actually grey in my IDE. This is definitely a scope issue.

Comment: You're declaring new `field` and `section` variables, not passing them. Remove them from your inner function declaration.

Comment: `rows.each(function(field, section) { ... })` should just be `rows.each(function() { ... })`

Comment: @TylerRoper But if I don't declare them in the second function, then they don't show up in my debugger locals, suggesting they aren't able to be used by the second function?

Comment: Those variables are available anywhere within `setValidationRowToFailure`. I can't speak for your debugger/IDE.

Comment: That sounds like an issue in your debugger, as they definitely will be available. Your current logic is overriding them, which is causing the problem.

Comment: @Jake12342134 That's because they are not local variables. The local scope "inherits" them from a scope further up. Check out [C# Variable scope in lambda expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions#variable-scope-in-lambda-expressions) that's pretty close to how this works in JS

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be, that the arguments defined here:

```
function setValidationRowToFailure(field, section) {
```

are being shadowed by these ones:

```
rows.each(function(field, section) {
```

You *should* be fine by removing the arguments inside the function passed to `.each`:

```
rows.each(function() {
```

Or just rename them:

```
rows.each(function(index, element) {
```

Note, that jQuery's `.each` passes an index variable as the first argument: https://api.jquery.com/each/#each-function